# Gapless thumbnail or content gallery in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, gallery, portfolio

I am trying to create a responsive thumbnail gallery using bootstrap 3.

I want it to be border less like this and some overlayed animated text.
Something close to this ( found on lovebootstrap.com)
http://www.riseragency.com/portfolio/

But all the example of the bootstrap thumbnail gallery I can find has large gaps based on the frame work like this
http://www.bootply.com/70929

But I can't get the gap less grid where the thumbnails are touching each other.

How can I reduce the gap like the example site above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll also need to remove the border, margin and padding styling from the `.thumbnail` class, as well as @jme11's very good tips:

```
#portfolio .thumbnail{
  border:0px;
  border-radius:0px;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}
```

**[Edit to your Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/WgQkBkTFFe)**

Comment: Thank you  Shawn! Visually it's what I wanted but it's not responsive anymore? Is it possible to make it responsive?

Comment: the bootply I updated has the same responsiveness as yours... if you want to add responsiveness, you've got to add [col-md-*] options, and make sure they are also being re-styled.

Comment: It worked! Thanks Shawn and everyone for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want the same effect that the riseagency site has you can use the masonry plugin.

If you simply want to remove the spacing between the thumbnails in your bootply example, then you can add an id to the row containing your portfolio like this:

```
<div id="portfolio" class="row">
```

and then add the following css rules:

```
#portfolio.row {
   margin:0;
}
#portfolio .col-xs-3 {
  padding:0;
}
```

This will remove the standard negative row margin and padding from the columns.  You don't want to do this for your whole site, hence the reason I've added the id to target the rules.

Comment: Thank you JME11. Will try it out soon.